# Filter right join data in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a simple table structure where each item row has a status. What I'm looking is to query for each status and count how many items use that state. It's possible that not all statuses will be used so I need to account for nulls and zero counts.

My table structures is as follows:

```
Table: Items
Id, State_id, Text, Status

Table: States
State_id, Name
```

This is what I have:

```
SELECT   statealias1_.State_id as y0_,
         count(this_.Id)       as y1_
FROM     Items this_
         right join States statealias1_
           on this_.State_id = statealias1_.State_id
WHERE    (not (statealias1_.State_id in (5, 6, 7, 8)) 
            or statealias1_.State_id is null)
         and (this_.Status = 'InProgress' 
            or this_.Status is null)
GROUP BY statealias1_.State_id;
```

This query works when all states included (there are 8 states and I'm excluding the second half). I'm not sure why this isn't returning me *all* states with count regardless of nulls as I appear to be including nulls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select i.State_id as y0_, count(i.Id) as y1_
from Items i
left join States s on i.State_id = s.State_Id and i.Status = 'InProgress'
group by i.State_id
```

Comment: My apologies. `State_id` and `Status` are two separate columns. I've modified my question accordingly.

Comment: As soon as I start filtering for the `Status` to be 'InProgress' any states that aren't used don't get returned.

Comment: @Nosila Try it like I put now.

Comment: This works. I'm really wondering why I can't use a right or left join without adding a join condition. Why can't I simply include the nulls in my where clause?

Comment: @Nosila The right join doesn't give NULL's so you can't use that. With the left join you could use NULL in the where clause but that isn't the proper way. If it works, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse it... start with your "Status" entries and LEFT JOIN to a pre-aggregated result set of what you DO want to include

```
select
      S.State_ID,
      COALESCE( PreAgg.ICount, 0 ) as StateCount
   from
      States S
         LEFT JOIN ( select I.State_ID, count(*) as ICount
                        from Items I
                        where NOT I.State_ID IN( 5, 6, 7, 8 )
                          AND I.Status = 'InProgress'
                        group by I.State_ID ) PreAgg
            on S.State_ID = PreAgg.State_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close, but you have it backwards from how I usually see it done.

```
SELECT s.State_id, COUNT(i.Id)
FROM States AS s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Items AS i ON i.State_id = s.State_id
WHERE ...
GROUP BY s.State_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL is correct, but you have a possible logic error in your where condition.

You have:

```
WHERE    (
             NOT (statealias1_.State_id in (5, 6, 7, 8)) 
             OR  statealias1_.State_id is null
)
AND      (this_.Status = 'InProgress' or this_.Status is null)
```

Did you mean:

```
WHERE    NOT (
                 statealias1_.State_id in (5, 6, 7, 8) 
                 OR statealias1_.State_id is null
         )
         AND ( this_.Status = 'InProgress' or this_.Status is null )
```